# worklight 6.2 how to schedule push notification to be send on 9 AM every day

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

We are using a interval based polling event source to push notifications for new request. we want to send a daily remainder daily to all devices at 9am. how to achieve this using worklight.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hi Reej and welcome to SO. Not showing what you have already tried will have your question downvoted most of the time.

Comment: Noted floum, will follow it in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not necessarily need Worklight to achieve this.
Worklight does not provide this.

You need to implement your own custom external logic/script that each day on 9AM will call the adapter that sends the notifications to the devices.

Comment: Hi Idan. Noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of two approaches:

- Just as Idan mentioned, the backend should be configured to call the adapter that sends notifications to the devices, at exactly 9 AM everyday.
- Eventsource definitions have a polling function that starts polling from the point the adapter is deployed. Set the polling interval ( in seconds for 24 hours). Deploy the adapter around 9 AM now. This is not the best approach. You should really look at configuring the backend to invoke the adapter at 9AM.

Comment: Hi Vivin. Thank you. We will configure the backend, as suggested